# pip off-line installation + what is the equivalent approach as yum repository with rpms but for .whl files

Tags: linux, bash, python, yum, pip

Dear friends and colleges

on our linux redhat servers we build yum repositories under `/var/yum.repo.d`
so yum actually get from this repositories the required rpm for installation

now we want to install with `pip` the `.whl` files

first approach is to install the `.whl` file with local installation as

```
   pip install --no-index --find-links "$WHL_FOLDER" "${WHL_FILE}"
```

but since we have `65` Linux machines , then we not want to locate the .whl on each linux machine

what we are thinking to do is to locate the `.whl` files under `repo_server` , as using `yum` - `/var/www/html` , but for `pip` installation I don't know what is the right approach

anyway the final `pip` approach should be install the `.whl` from repository as we did in yum

example

```
pip install some-package.whl
```

so please advice how to build the repositories for pip installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`pip config`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_config/) on local (user) or global level. Either on `/etc/pip.conf` for global or `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` for per-user config.

```
[install]
no-index=yes
find-links=/path/to/local/wheels
```

You can also use `pip config` command.

```bsh
pip config --global install.find-links=/path/to/local/wheels
```

But override `no-index` might cause some [problems](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4138), however I haven't tried it before.

If you want to setup pip to download from local repository by default, use [`index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-index-url) and [`index`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_search/)

```
[global]
index=http://repository.local/repo/pypi
index-url=http://repository.local/repo/simple
trusted-host=repository.local
```

Comment: but I not understand how the /pip/pip.conf get the .whl from repo_server ? because you not mentioned the path of the  repo_server machine

Comment: You mean repo_server like this? https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/

Comment: if python.example.com , is remote server that hold all .whk files then this is what I mean yes

Comment: I've included the example for local repository.

Comment: so I need to configure the - /etc/pip.conf as /etc/yum.conf and where to locate the pip repo file that include the - [global]
index=http://repository.local/repo/pypi
index-url=http://repository.local/repo/simple
trusted-host=repository.local ?

Comment: Read again the link I gave on _"Manual" repository_ section. What do you mean by `/etc/pip.conf` as `/etc/yum.conf` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115867/discussion-between-jessica-and-yudaka).